# Can DEBUG level messages be excluded from system.log?

Tags: administration, best-practice, logging

I'm working on a large Magento installation setup by another developer.  Logging is disabled in the live environment which struck me as odd.  While testing the code with logging enabled locally it seems it's extremely verbose, generating a huge number of DEBUG entries.

Is it possible to limit the system log to capture only higher threshold messages?  If not then am I incorrect in assuming logging should be enabled on the live site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Mage::log method because there is no way to overwrite it.

```
if (is_null($level) || $level == Zend_Log::DEBUG) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug mode might be on. Go to System - Configuration - Developer - Debug and if the Profiler is set to Yes, disable it.
This [article](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/203-troubleshooting-magento/enabling-the-debug-profiler-in-magento) is a bit old but it might help you to disable the debug mode. This [post](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-magento-for-development-debug-mode/) might be also usefull.